# Centering on Twitter Bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I thought `text-align` works in Twitter Bootstrap but it doesn't? I'm not sure what's going on. Is there an alternative to centering or am I just going to have to use margin? Sorry for the overkill with the style `text-align`. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

```
<div class="row-fluid span12" style="text-align:center;">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="text-align:center;">
        <li style="text-align:center;">Skills</li>
        <li style="text-align:center;">Music</li>
        <li style="text-align:center;">Things I Read</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be because bootstrap sets the anchors to be display: block. Text alignment works on inline and inline-block elements. Have you otherwise customized the bootstrap css? The nav pills should have the text centered anyway, unless you've specified a width, because it should just be adding even padding to the block-level anchor element.

Comment: Solved. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: Take that back, I need nav-pills. I haven't made any width changes nor messed with bootstrap css.

Comment: Is it that you want to center the pills in the container, or the text inside the pills?

Comment: to center the nav div on the page itself.

Comment: Then text-align:center definitely won't work, it's for text alignment, not for centering block-level elements. Are your nav pills always going to have the same width or be the same number? They're all set to float: left, so if you change the container width and set an offset, you can "center" it and still be using the bootstrap grid, like: <div class="span8 offset2"></div> instead of <div class="span12"></div>

Comment: The problem I realized with using offset was that it doesn't center it exactly. It's always off by just a little bit. Should I use offset and then set a margin to adjust it accordingly?

Comment: Fixed it. Just used margin 0 auto, float none, and set a width. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah I've run into the same issue before; and I agree the offset solution isn't really centering it either. :-/ found this, anyway, in my googling: http://jsfiddle.net/rfkrocktk/hcQ48/